# rendering JSON in view

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing an app in `node.js`, I have the following code.

API for retrieving topic from DB

```
allTopics = function (req, res) {
  db.Topic.all({limit: 10}).success(function (topics) {
    res.send(topics)
  });
};
```

Route for topics index

```
  app.get('/topics', function (req, res){
    res.render('topics/index.ejs',{ topics : allTopics })
  });
```

Is the above code correct for route?

Also I have `index.ejs` file where I want to list all the topics (i.e. retrieve data from json response). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as-is won't work but you could rewrite it as follows:

```
// notice how I am passing a callback rather than req/res
allTopics = function (callback) {
  db.Topic.all({limit: 10}).success(function (topics) {
    callback(topics);
  });
};


// call allTopics and render inside the callback when allTopics() 
// has finished.  I renamed "allTopics" to "theData" in the callback
// just to make it clear one is the data one is the function.
app.get('/topics', function (req, res){
  allTopics(function(theData) {
    res.render('topics/index.ejs',{ topics : theData });
  });
});
```